# python defining multiple classes with decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming, tornado

I have the base class:

```
class BaseGameHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    name = 'Base'
    def get(self):
        self.render(self.name + ".html")
```

Now, I need to define a few subclasses of this but the thing is, they have to have a decorator. Equivalent code would be:

```
@route('asteroid')
class AsteroidGameHandler(BaseGameHandler):
    name = 'asteroid'


@route('blah')
class BlahGameHandler(BaseGameHandler):
    name = 'blah'
```

and maybe a few more. 
A little background here: This is a tornado web app and the `@route` decorator allows you to map `/blah` to `BlahGameHandler`. This code maps `/blah` to `BlahGameHandler` and `/asteroid` to `AsteroidGameHandler`.

So I thoughtI should use metaprogramming in python and define all these classes on the fly. I tried the following which doesn't work(and by doesn't work I mean the final web-app throws 404 on both `/asteroid` and `/blah`):

```
game_names = ['asteroid', 'blah']

games = list([game, type('%sGameHandler' % (game.title()), (BaseGameHandler,), {'name': game})] for game in game_names)

for i in xrange(len(games)):
    games[i][1] = route(games[i][0])(games[i][1])
```

What am I missing? Aren't these two codes equivalent when run?

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a problem description. What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your code looks like it would work *just fine*, apart from not setting the objects in your globals. What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: So, where does `route()` come from? Perhaps the class decorator has additional requirements, like the class being a module global?

Comment: Is this the `@route` decorator from [`tornroutes`](https://github.com/nod/tornroutes) or something else? Do you actually call `route.get_routes()` to list the routes at some point?

Comment: The route decorator comes from here: https://github.com/troolee/tornado-routes/blob/master/tornado_routes.py#L127

Comment: I see that [`tornroutes` generates classes for routes too](https://github.com/nod/tornroutes/blob/master/tornroutes/__init__.py) so there is *no* reason for your code not to work unless you forget to use `route.get_routes()`.

Comment: no, not tornroutes, tornado-routes

Comment: I think I get what the issue is, on [line 91](https://github.com/troolee/tornado-routes/blob/master/tornado_routes.py#L91), it calls `dir(module)` and `dir[module]` doesn't give all these handlers because they are not assigned a name in the top level of the module. Do you have any suggestions as to how to fix that?

Comment: Already suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that you use only looks for global class objects in your module.

Set each class as a global; the [`globals()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) gives you access to your module namespace as a dictionary:

```
for i in xrange(len(games)):
    globals()[games[i][1].__name__] = route(games[i][0])(games[i][1])
```

The `include()` code does *not* look for your views in lists.

To be specific, `include()` uses the following loop to detect handlers:

```
for member in dir(module):
    member = getattr(module, member)
    if isinstance(member, type) and issubclass(member, web.RequestHandler) and hasattr(member, 'routes'):
        # ...
    elif isinstance(member, type) and issubclass(member, web.RequestHandler) and hasattr(member, 'route_path'):
        # ...
    elif isinstance(member, type) and issubclass(member, web.RequestHandler) and hasattr(member, 'rest_route_path'):
        # ...
```

`dir(module)` only considers top-level objects.